# AIX 6.1 starting xhost + from inittab at the boot time

Tags: x11, aix

Everytime after restarting the servers, I have to run `xhost +` from console prompt.

Does anyone have any idea about enabling `xhost +` from `inittab` file?

Comment: Why do you want to run `xhost +`? If you tell us, we'll have a better idea of where to run it (though I can tell you `inittab` is definitely the wrong place), and possibly we'll be able to suggest something more secure.

Comment: Oracle requires Xwindows and we have Unix machine with a graphics adapter available as resource for this in a remote site. To avoid going to remote site just to run xhost + after each restart of the system, for this reason we are looking for a way to have  xhost  running after each reboot.

Comment: How is the connection between the Oracle machine and the machine running with the graphics adapter established? For that matter, how are you starting the X session?

Comment: Via ethernet, the hostname of the server with graphics card is explicitly defined in one of the Oracle configuration file. For now, we go to remote site and issue xhost + on the graphics console every time there is a reboot.

Comment: @AlBouazizi The configuration you have sounds a bit crazy.  I suggest you describe your setup on dba.SE and ask for suggestions on changing it.  Oracle DB doesn't require GUI to run and for configuration it doesn't need to run on the server.  Further if you need a display host I suggest using a Windows machine with CygwinX or similar.  It will be cheaper too.

Comment: @Karlson:<br> /u01/XYZ1/db/tech_st/10.2.0/appsutil/orasid_host.xml
<br>grep display $CONTEXT_FILE

 

<oa_environment type="generic_service">

         <DISPLAY oa_var="s_display" osd="unix">host.domain.com:0.0</DISPLAY>

      </oa_environment>
<br> i don't have problem with any db configuration<br> my question was how to run xhost + on every reboot of the system?

Comment: @AlBouazizi So why do you need to run graphical tools on the machine running Oracle DB displaying wherever?  You can run the tool set on any machine without having `xhost +` connecting to a remote DB.

Comment: @Let's assume we don't have Db, back to my original question, how to run xhost + on every reboot of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a system service you really shouldn't put this into `inittab`.

If you need to run `xhost +` from a console you should put it into it's initialization script.